# ERROR: *** unrecognised codec libav ***

Tags: camera, streaming-video, streaming, libcamera

I'm attempting to run the sample command found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#libav-integration-with-libcamera-vid) for streaming video data to an mp4 container using `libcamera-vid` and the `libav` integration. I have the latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite installed using the Raspberry Pi Imager and all packages upgraded to latest. When I run:

```
libcamera-vid --codec libav -o test.mp4
```

I receive the following:

```
ERROR: *** unrecognised codec libav ***
```

I can't find anywhere in the documentation or online how to resolve this issue. I've tried installing `libavcodec-dev`, `libavcodec58`, and `libavcodec-extra58` to no avail. What do I need to install so that I can run the above command, which is found in the docs for `libcamera-vid`?

Comment: You cannot used mp4(this is for cv2.VideoCapture). When using libvav, you use mkv or raw.

Comment: @toyotaSupra according to [the docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#libav-integration-with-libcamera-vid): "These output formats can be specified as containers (e.g. mkv, **mp4**, avi) or stream output (e.g. h264 or mpegts)."

Comment: You are right. I scroll at the bottom. Actually, I'm using picamera2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the full `libcamera-apps` package, Raspberry Pi OS Lite only ships with `libcamera-apps-lite`.

`libav` based functionality got removed from `libcamera-apps-lite` because it pulls in X11 dependencies (relevant [bug report](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/315#issuecomment-1179705105)).

Comment: Great to know, thank you! Would be wonderful if they added that relevant bit to the `libav` section of the docs.